# simple tools to extract Re,Im,Abs... of any complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I've developped my own set of simple yet powerful tools to work on complex functions. I would like to know if these simple tools are currently used in complex analysis.

Let's $z = x + i y = |z| e^{i\theta}$ and it's complex conjuguate $z^* = x - i y = |z| e^{-i\theta}$, where $\theta = \text{Arctan}(y/x)$, we can write:

$
\frac{1}{2i}\text{Log}\left( \frac{z}{z^*} \right) =\text{  }\frac{1}{2i}\text{Log}\left( \frac{|z|e^{i \theta }}{|z|e^{-i \theta }} \right) = \theta =\arg(z)
$

$
\sqrt{z z^*}=\sqrt{ |z|e^{i \theta }|z|e^{-i \theta }}=|z|=\text{Abs}(z)
$

$
\frac{1}{2}( z + z^*)=|z|\frac{(e^{i \theta }+e^{-i \theta })}{2}= \mathfrak{Re}(z)
$

$
\frac{1}{2}( \frac{z + z^*}{|z|})=\frac{(e^{i \theta }+e^{-i \theta })}{2}=\text{Cos}(\theta )
$

$
\frac{1}{2i}( z - z^*)=|z|\frac{(e^{i \theta }-e^{-i \theta })}{2i}=\mathfrak{Im}(z)
$

$
\frac{1}{2i}( \frac{z - z^*}{|z|})=\frac{(e^{i \theta }-e^{-i \theta })}{2i}=\text{Sin}(\theta )
$

Let's now $f(z)$ be any complex function or composition of functions $g(...f(z))$, the same results hold when plugging  $f(z)$ and  $f(z^*)$ instead of $z$ and $z^*$, giving the tools set:

$
\frac{1}{2i}\text{Log}\left( \frac{f(z) }{f(z^*)} \right) =\text{  }\frac{1}{2i}\text{Log}\left( \frac{|f(z)|e^{i \theta }}{|f(z)|e^{-i \theta }} \right) = \theta =\arg(f(z))
$

$
\sqrt{f(z) f(z^*)}=\sqrt{ |f(z)|e^{i \theta }|f(z)|e^{-i \theta }}=|f(z)|=\text{Abs}(f(z))
$

$
\frac{1}{2}\left( f(z)+f(z^*) \right)=|f(z)|\frac{\left(e^{i \theta }+e^{-i \theta }\right)}{2}= \mathfrak{Re}(f(z))
$

$
\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{f(z)+f(z^*)}{|f(z)|}\right)=\frac{\left(e^{i \theta }+e^{-i \theta }\right)}{2}=\text{Cos}(\theta )
$

$
\frac{1}{2i}\left( f(z)-f(z^*)\right)=|f(z)|\frac{\left(e^{i \theta }-e^{-i \theta }\right)}{2i}=\mathfrak{Im}(f(z))
$

$
\frac{1}{2i}\left( \frac{f(z)-f( z^*)}{|f(z)|}\right)=\frac{\left(e^{i \theta }-e^{-i \theta }\right)}{2i}=\text{Sin}(\theta )
$

So, are these simple formulas using $f(z)$ and $f(z^*)$ to extract the complex components of functions known? Is there in complex analysis any litterature about?

EDIT: after comments, may be we should consider $f(z)^*$ instead of $f(z^*)$ ...?

Here are some examples showing their use.

Using the formula for the Zeta function $\zeta (\mathit{z})=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{1-p_k{}^{-\mathit{z}}}$ for $z>1$, where $p_k$ is the $k^{th}$ prime number, we can quite easily find:
$$
\sqrt{\zeta (z) \zeta(z^*)}=|\zeta (\mathit{z})|=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty } \sqrt{\frac{p_k{}^{2x}}{p_k{}^{2x}-2p_k{}^x\cos \left(y \log \left(p_k\right)\right)+1}}
$$

$$
\frac{1}{2i}\text{Log}\left( \frac{\zeta(z) }{\zeta( z^*)} \right) = \arg( \zeta (z) )=-\sum_ {k = 1}^{\infty}\sum _ {q = 1}^{\infty}\frac {1} {k p_q^{k x}}\text {Sin}( k y \text{ Log}(p_q ) )
$$

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The formulas for real part and imaginary part are pretty standard, your formulas for sine and cosine follow directly from Euler's formula. The formula using the logarithm is one particular definition of the logarithm. The formulas for the functions you gave below are not quite correct, since you omit the $z$ dependence of $\theta$ and $f(z)^* \ne f(z^*)$ in general.

Comment: The formula for $\sin \theta$ is also incorrect. (There's an $i$ missing in the denominator.)

Comment: @filmor, the formulas, in my concern, are correct every time i use them. The fact seems to be that complex transformations preserve angles.

Comment: thanks you, @mfr - corrected!

Comment: @Eddy, what do you mean by "complex transformation"? What do you mean by "preserve angles"? The first set of equations is very well known and used all the time while the second set relies on a property ($f(z)^* = f(z^*)$) that you neither define nor show for the function you apply it to.

Comment: @filmor, no, I mean that if $arg(f(z))=teta$, then $arg(f(z^*))=-teta$, but that's right: i don't demonstrate anything, just say that it seems to work any time.

Comment: You are not only using $\arg(f(z)) = \theta \Leftrightarrow \arg(f(z^*)) = -\theta$ but also $|f(z)| = |f(z^*)|$ which is together (if I'm not mistaken) equivalent to $f(z)^* = f(z^*)$.

Comment: A simple concrete example to illustrate @filmor's point: Let $f(z) = z+i$. Then $f(i) = 2i$, but $f(-i) = 0$, so neither $\arg f(z^*) = -\arg f(z)$ nor $|f(z)|=|f(z^*)|$ holds in general for holomorphic functions.

Comment: The identity $f(z)^* = f(z^*)$ holds if $f$ is entire and all of its Maclaurin coefficients are real, for instance.

Comment: @mfr, may be you should consider the following funtions: $f(z)=z+i$ and $f(z^*)=z^*-i$, so you get, for $abs(f(z))$ something like this: [plot on wolfram|alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28+%7Babs+%28+x+%2B+I*y+%2B+I+%29%2Csqrt+%28%28+x+%2B+I*y+%2B+I%29*%28+x+-+I*y-+I%29%29%7D++%2C+%7Bx%2C+-1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-2%2C+2%7D+%29)

Comment: @Eddy, if $f(z) = z+i$ then $f(z^*) = z^* + i$ though.

Comment: yes, right @antonio. I suppose that the formulas work correctly for real-values coefficients of z...

Comment: No, they don't. The coefficients Antonio was talking about are a property of the function, not the parameter (the Maclaurin coefficients are the Taylor coefficients at zero, i.e. $a_n = \frac{\partial^n f(0)}{n!}$). This is quite a special set of functions, essentially all real analytic functions extended to the complex plane.

Comment: Eddy, what is your question? It would be great if you edited your post in a way we could quickly see what exactly you want in an answer.

Comment: @Ian, I would like to know if the set of formulas making use of $f(z)$ and $f(z^*)$ to extract complex components of functions are used in complex analysis, if there's any litterature or reference about their use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, are these simple formulas using $f(z)$ and $f(z^*)$ to extract the
>   complex components of functions known? Is there in complex analysis
>   any litterature **(sic)** about?

Yes. When you have provided correct formulas, they are standard identities that can be found in introductory texts about complex numbers. You have written them in a form applicable to *functions* instead of complex *numbers*, and I believe you are asking if this is a heretofore unknown way of writing formulas for complex functions. However, I think you should note that note that for a fixed $z\in \mathbb{C}$, $f(z)$ is just another number in $\mathbb{C}$. If a formula holds for an arbitrary complex number $z$, then since $f(z)$ is also a complex number, the formula will hold for that number too. You have applied known identities to about complex numbers to complex functions, but $f$ maps $\mathbb C$ to itself, so you're still talking about known identities on $\mathbb C$.

To see this, think of defining a new complex variable, $y=f(z)$. Now rewrite all the functional identities you presented in this new variable (i.e. replace $f(z)$ with $y$ wherever you see it), and you've recovered the original, known identities, except you've replaced $z$ with $y$. What's the fundamental difference between $y$ and $z$? They both represent arbitrary numbers in the complex plane. The point is that since $f(z)\in\mathbb C$, $y\in\mathbb C$, and $z\in\mathbb C$, you can write the identities, which are properties of *any* numbers in $\mathbb C$, in terms of any of these you like. All these representations are valid. Sets of formulas in terms of complex functions may not appear explicitly in the literature, but because complex functions *are* complex numbers for all their arguments, you can freely replace $z$ by $f(z)$ in the formulas. They both represent arbitrary numbers in $\mathbb C$ and the formulas naturally still hold.

Comment: Eddy, I read through some of your posts, and commend you for discovering so much about complex analysis with little formal training. If you want to delve deeper, I could suggest you look into any introductory textbook about complex numbers or complex analysis. I like this one for free: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/winter99/complex.html

Comment: thanks you for the link! Indeed, i'm a graphist, not a mathematician...

Comment: but I use the formulas, and as so far, it works well. But I think that the problem is that one should prove that if $\arg(f(z))=\theta$ then $\arg(f(z^*))=-\theta$, and as many comments point out, this may only be true for real-valued fonctions (or series). but choosing $f(z)^*$ instead of $f(z^*)$ should work fine?

Comment: Yes $f(z)^*$ in place of $f(z^*)$ in your formulas is the most general form. This follows directly from formally substituting $z\rightarrow f(z)$. For real valued functions, you have $f(z^*)=f(z)^*=f(z)=\Re(f(z))$, which gives the formulas you provided.

Answer (score 1):

You will, in fact, need to use $f(z)^*,$ instead, as pointed out in the comments, since (in general) $f(z^*)$ need not be identically equal to $f(z)^*$.

In point of fact, if $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C,$ then one necessary condition to have $f(z^*)=f(z)^*$ is that $f$ be a real-valued function when restricted to the reals. Indeed, if there is some real $r$ such that $f(r)=w$ for some $w\in\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R,$ then $$f(r^*)=f(r)=w\ne w^*=f(r)^*.$$

Antonio Vargas points out that an entire function with all Maclaurin coefficients real satisfies the desired property, but there are other functions that do the trick and aren't even holomorphic, such as $f(z)=\frac12(z+z^*).$